# How To Parse JSON Case Insensitive In Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, parsing, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data Factory and we have the following 4 different formats of JSON data stored in the (source) SQL Database:

**Source SQL Table (Having JSON Payload)**

| RequestID | Endpoint | Payload |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | /Customer | { "iD": 1, "firstName": "Alvin", "lastName" : "Chang", "countryVisited": ["US","CA","JP","UK"] } |
| 0002 | /Customer | { "Id": 2, "FirstName": "Mike", "LastName" : "Smith", "CountryVisited": ["US","UK"] } |
| 0003 | /Customer | { "ID": 3, "FIRSTNAME": "Shelly", "LASTNAME" : "Bose", "COUNTRYVISITED": ["JP","AU"] } |
| 0004 | /Customer | { "id": 4, "firstname": "Chris", "lastname" : "EStrada", "countryvisited": ["IN","CA","UK"] } |

We are trying to parse the Payload and store it into another database (sink) table as follows:

**Target (Sink) SQL Table:**

| ID | FirstName | LastName | Countries Visited |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alvin | Chang | US~CA~JP~UK |
| 2 | Mike | Smith | US~UK |
| 3 | Shelly | Bose | JP~AU |
| 4 | Chris | Estrada | IN~CA~UK |

The source Table has the following JSON data in different formats. The property names are the same but in different formats (mixed cases). I am not sure how to define the Output Column Type Expression able to parse all 4 different formats.

**Format 1**
{
"iD": 1,
"firstName": "Alvin",
"lastName" : "Chang",
"countryVisited": ["US","CA","JP","UK"]
}

**Format 2**
{
"Id": 2,
"FirstName": "Mike",
"LastName" : "Smith",
"CountryVisited": ["US","UK"]
}

**Format 3**
{
"ID": 3,
"FIRSTNAME": "Shelly",
"LASTNAME" : "Bose",
"COUNTRYVISITED": ["JP","AU"]
}

**Format 4**
{
"id": 4,
"firstname": "Chris",
"lastname" : "EStrada",
"countryvisited": ["IN","CA","UK"]
}

Here is my DataFlow for your reference:
[image: Data Flow]

Comment: What column names you want? I think the Format2 is the correct header right?

Comment: The problem is customers are sending the Payload in different formats but the structure is the same so having problems parsing different formats where property names are the same but in different cases (e.g. firstName, FirstName, FIRSTNAME, firstname etc.) Is it possible to convert all given property names (only) to lowercase and then map to output column type expression as (id as integer, firstname as string, lastname as string, countryvisited as string).

Comment: Is your JSON is an array of JSON with different formats? or each object is coming as seperate JSON object file?

Comment: I have added the Source Table in the original post above to show how the data is stored in our source table it's not an array and single payload for each request but in different formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve your requirement using below approach.

**NOTE**: In this approach, I have used certain characters in JSON to split and made a list of keys. This approach only works for this case (for this JSON structure), if your JSON structure is different you need to change the characters according to your JSON.

First, I have used derived column transformations to find the list of keys in each row(json string).

For that, I have used below expression and generated a new array column called `array`. Here, give your number of columns in the JSON string (I have given 4).

```
slice(split(Payload,'":'),1,4)
```

It gave me the following array column.

[image]

Then, in next derived column I have used below expression to get the list of keys in each JSON string.

```
mapIndex(array,substringIndex(#item,'"',-1))
```

[image]

Now, I have used another derived column transformation. In this I have replaced each element in keys array with lower(keys).

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(Payload,keys[1],lower(keys[1])),keys[2],lower(keys[2])),keys[3],lower(keys[3])),keys[4],lower(keys[4]))
```

As all keys are in same case, now we can use parse transformation on this.

[image]

Give the below parse configurations.

[image]

```
(id as integer,
        firstname as string,
        lastname as string,
        countryvisited as string[])
```

**Parse Result:**

[image]

Now, use select transformation Rule based mapping to only get the required columns.

[image]

As you want the last column `countryvisited` to be a string separated with `~`, I took another derived column transformation and used below expression. `join()` is not supported in dataflow expression, so I used replace as per the requirement.

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(toString(countryvisited), '[', ''),']',''),'"',''),',','~')
```

**Result:**

[image]

Add an SQL table as sink and the data will be copied to the SQL table.

**My Dataflow JSON for your reference:**

```
{
    "name": "dataflow2",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumnForSplitArray"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumnForKeysArray"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DerivedColumnReplaceKeys"
                },
                {
                    "name": "parse1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn4"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          RequestID as string,",
                "          Payload as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     isolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',",
                "     format: 'table') ~> source1",
                "source1 derive(array = slice(split(Payload,'\":'),1,4)) ~> derivedColumnForSplitArray",
                "derivedColumnForSplitArray derive(keys = mapIndex(array,substringIndex(#item,'\"',-1))) ~> derivedColumnForKeysArray",
                "derivedColumnForKeysArray derive(Payload = replace(replace(replace(replace(Payload,keys[1],lower(keys[1])),keys[2],lower(keys[2])),keys[3],lower(keys[3])),keys[4],lower(keys[4]))) ~> DerivedColumnReplaceKeys",
                "DerivedColumnReplaceKeys parse(Payload = Payload ? (id as integer,",
                "          firstname as string,",
                "          lastname as string,",
                "          countryvisited as string[]),",
                "     format: 'json',",
                "     documentForm: 'singleDocument') ~> parse1",
                "parse1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          each(Payload,match(true()))",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "select1 derive(countryvisited = replace(replace(replace(replace(toString(countryvisited), '[', ''),']',''),'\"',''),',','~')) ~> derivedColumn4",
                "derivedColumn4 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     deletable:false,",
                "     insertable:true,",
                "     updateable:false,",
                "     upsertable:false,",
                "     format: 'table',",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     errorHandlingOption: 'stopOnFirstError') ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for creating the sample flow with all the examples and screenshots it was very helpful but now when I am working on the real data (almost 30+ properties) realize those properties are dynamic so some of the records only have 5 properties compared to others having in between 5 - 30+ properties. Is it possible to run the replace in loop based on the returned array length to replace each property to lowercase (one by one) and save it into the final returned lowercase JSON format?

Comment: As I mentioned, this method will only work for the given JSON structure. If your JSON properties changes like that I think ADF dataflow won't be enough to achieve your requirement. It's better to build your logic using any programming language. If you want use python, Call databricks notebook from ADF. In darabricks notebook implement your code to replace keys by loop and write the data to blob again. After Notebook activity, call your dataflow activity in ADF to transform further to sink table.